# help with a null pointer exception in my program

Tags: java, null, nullpointerexception

problem occurs at return this.permission.contains(permission);

```
package sef.module15.activity;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class PermissionList implements Permissable {

    private Set<Permission> permission;

    /**
     * Creates a permission object and provides an identifier for it
     * 
     * @param permissionID
     */

    public PermissionList(String permissionID) {

        if (permissionID == null) {
            this.permission = new HashSet<Permission>();
        }

    }

    public Set<Permission> getPermission() {

        return permission;

    }

    public void removePermission(Permission... permission) {
        this.permission.remove(permission);

    }

    public void setPermission(Permission... permission) {
        if (permission == null) {
            setPermission(permission);
        }

    }

    public boolean isPermissable(Permission permission) {
        return this.permission.contains(permission);
    }
}
```

here's the permissable.java

```
package sef.module15.activity;

import java.util.Set;

public interface Permissable {

    public void setPermission(Permission... permission);

    public void removePermission(Permission... permission);

    public Set<Permission> getPermission();

    public boolean isPermissable(Permission permission);
}
```

and heres permission.java

```
package sef.module15.activity;

public enum Permission {
    READ,
    WRITE,
    CREATE,
    DELETE,
    EXECUTE;

}
```

Comment: What is the "calling code" i.e., who calls this class and it's methods?

Comment: setPermission looks somewhat recursive if permission is null also.

Comment: updated who calls the class and the methods involved

Comment: Not enough. WHERE is the concrete class implementing the interface and the actual methods it calls??? The calling flow = stack trace printed when you get an exception! (Your related classes) Update with the actual line of code(s) that calls setPermission or getPermission etc.,

Answer (score 0):

The set is null if permissionID is passed to the program ? That is a problem

```
  if (permissionID == null) {
        this.permission = new HashSet<Permission>();
    }
```

Give us the stack trace and the calling code. It is difficult to pinpoint the source of the NPE without this

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/javasummerschool/source/browse/trunk/SEF/src/sef/module15/activity/PermissionList.java

Answer (score 0):

If the constructor's `permissionID` is null, `permissionSet` is never assigned a value.  Thus, if the permissionID is passed, the methods which access permissionSet will all throw a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

1. If `permissionID` passed in constructor is `not-null`, then your instance variable `permission` is never initialised. Hence, pointing to that will give you a `NPE`.
2. Your `setPermission()` implementation is recursive. A recursion that will not end gracefully and will never add anything to your `Set`.

**Possible fixes:**

Initialise your `Set` in constructor like below,

```
public PermissionList(Permission permission) {
    permissions = new HashSet<Permission>(); // Change your Set name to permissions
    if (permission != null) {
        permissions.add(permission);
    }    
}
```

Implementation of `setPermissions()` method,

```
public void setPermissions(Permission... permissions) {
    for(Permission per : permissions) {
        this.permissions.add(per);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rebel: From where, JUnit came into play?

Answer (score 0):

thats because you are trying to check a property from a not initialized variable. Try that to control if you permission variable and the argument passed to the function are not null:

```
public boolean isPermissable(Permission p) {
        boolean exit = false;
        if((permission != null) && (p != null)){
              exit = permission.contains(p);
        }
        return exit;
    }
```

anyway i recommend you to create an empty constructor for your class, and initialize all the variables

```
PermissionList(){
    permission = new HashSet();
}
```

**EDIT**

I just found a strange thing in your code. Here

```
public PermissionList(String permissionID) {

        if (permissionID == null) {
            this.permission = new HashSet<Permission>();
        }

    }
```

You will never initialize your permission property, unless you call the constructor that way: `PermissionList myPermission = PermissionList(null)`, because you dont have an empty constructor like `PermissionList myPermission = PermissionList()`, and any string that you pass as permissionID will not be null.

Why you use the permissionID argument? Where do you store it?

Thats why you get a NPE wen you call this.permission in your code. You never initilize the permission property.